# Local state does not re-render the component when using useLocalStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

I have a following component

```
const showMoreDom = (text, onClick) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text}
      <span className='anchor' onClick={onClick}>
        {' '}
        show more{' '}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

const showLessDom = (text, onClick) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text}
      <span className='anchor' onClick={onClick}>
        {' '}
        show less{' '}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

export const ReadMore: React.FunctionComponent<IReadMore> = ({ comment }) => {
  const state = useLocalStore(() => ({
    isShowLess: false,
    handleShowLess: () => {
      state.isShowLess = false
    },
    handleShowMore: () => {
      state.isShowLess = true
    }
  }))
  const text = comment || ''
  const maxLength = MAX_LENGTH
  const textLength = text.length
  if (textLength > maxLength && !state.isShowLess) {
    const clippedText = text.slice(0, 14) + '...'
    return showMoreDom(clippedText, state.handleShowMore)
  }
  if (state.isShowLess) {
    const overflownText = text
    return showLessDom(overflownText, state.handleShowLess)
  }
  return <Typography className={classNames({})}>{text}</Typography>
}
```

Here, I am trying to show , the less and more functionality. In this component, when I click on show more then it function gets called onclick but after that the rerender does not happen.
So, returned div does not get rendered.

Can any one help me wit this ?

Comment: it seems like you're directly manipulating the component state and should be using the `useState()` hook instead. What does the `useLocalStore` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your component with `observer` decorator (or HOC, whatever you want to call it).

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react"

const ReadMore = observer(({ comment }) => {
    const state = useLocalStore(() => ({

    // Your other code here
})
```

Basically every time you use observable inside component you need to do that so component could react to `observable` changes.

More info here https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html#using-context-to-pass-observables-around

Comment: thank for the answer. A question, Trying to do show less / show more thing. Here I am using number of characters basis , is there any though which I can do it using number of lines basis like after three lines show , show more part  any help would be great

Comment: You probably can't easily do that with javascript, because if you element is responsive then 3 lines could be 100 chars or it could be 300 chars depends on the width of container. But you can do that with css, check this article about `line-clamp` property https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/

Comment: Yes Actually I did this. I tried using but no luck.

Comment: It should work in all modern browsers, don't forget about `-webkit-` prefix and also use `overflow` and `white-space` properties too. Just like in article